# fchollet 5.4-visualizing-what-convnets-learn input_13:0 is both fed and fetched error

Tags: keras, keras-layer

Using Keras 2.2.4, I'm working my way though this notebook [5.4-visualizing-what-convnets-learn](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.4-visualizing-what-convnets-learn.ipynb) , except I switched the model with a [unet one provided by Kaggle-Carvana-Image-Masking-Challenge](https://github.com/petrosgk/Kaggle-Carvana-Image-Masking-Challenge/blob/master/model/u_net.py#L250) .  The first layer of the Kaggle model looks like this, followed by the rest of the example code.

```
def get_unet_512(input_shape=(512, 512, 3),
                 num_classes=1):
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)

...

Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_13 (InputLayer)           (None, 512, 512, 3)  0    
...

from keras import models
layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers[:8]]
activation_model = models.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=layer_outputs)
activations = activation_model.predict(img_tensor)
```

Now the error I am getting is

```
InvalidArgumentError: input_13:0 is both fed and fetched.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by:

```
layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers[:8]]
```

, and it says that the first layer(input layer) is both fed and fetched.

Here's a workaround:

```
import keras.backend as K
layer_outputs = [K.identity(layer.output) for layer in model.layers[:8]]
```

EDIT: 
Full example, code adapted from: [Mask_RCNN - run_graph](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/dca5e81f48440dc0a0c828a7af9b5001b558b4f5/mrcnn/model.py#L2669)

```
import numpy as np
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten

model = Sequential()
ip = Input(shape=(512,512,3,))
fl = Flatten()(ip)
d1 = Dense(20, activation='relu')(fl)
d2 = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(d1)

model = Model(ip, d2)
model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy')
model.summary()

layer_outputs = [K.identity(layer.output) for layer in model.layers]
#layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers] #fails
kf = K.function([ip], layer_outputs)
activations = kf([np.random.random((1,512,512,3))])
print(activations)
```

Comment: thank you keineahnung2345. I made that change and was getting this error ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("Identity_229:0", shape=(?, 512, 512, 3), dtype=float32)` i changed the problematic line to layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers[1:8]] based on your note, and think it's working ok. Do you see any problems with that approach?

Comment: @foobar8675 Sorry, I haven't notice the line of `
layer_outputs = [K.identity(layer.output) for layer in model.layers]`. Your solution which discards input layer is quite reasonable. But if you want the input layer to be included anyway, you can use the solution I added.

Comment: Thank you so much!